# JS function addEventListener just works on the first element of my list

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I display a user list and at the end of each user I add 2 buttons, one for edit and the other to delete the user, my big problem is that only the buttons of my first element of my list work.

This code displays my list

```
<tbody>
            <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count($users->datos); $i++ ): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 0 20px;"><?php echo $users->datos[$i]["email"  ]; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding: 0 20px;"><?php echo $users->datos[$i]["paterno"]; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding: 0 20px;"><?php echo $users->datos[$i]["materno"]; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding: 0 20px;"><?php echo $users->datos[$i]["nombre" ]; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding: 0 20px;">
                        <?php
                        echo preg_replace(PHONE_NUMBER, "($1) $2-$3", $users->datos[$i]["movil"]);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td id="botones">
                        <form id="ed" method="POST">
                            <input  type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="<?php echo $users->datos[$i]["tokenA"]; ?>">
                            
                            <button type="submit" id="<?php echo $users->datos[$i]["id"]; ?>" class="buttonDelete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                            <button type="submit" id="<?php echo $users->datos[$i]["id"]; ?>" class="buttonEdit"  ><i class="fas fa-edit"     ></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tbody>
```

[image: This is the image of my table]

And this is my javascript code

```
const formEditDel = document.querySelector('form#ed');
const userDel = formEditDel.querySelectorAll('[class="buttonDelete"]')
const userEdit = formEditDel.querySelectorAll('[class="buttonEdit"]')


eventListeners();

function eventListeners(event) {

    userDel.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', markDeleted);
    });

    userEdit.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', userEdited);
    });

}
```

I really don't know what to do, so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The question does not detail what `markDeleted` or `userEdited` do.

Comment: I would try posting the code for `markDeleted` and `userEdited`. However, one observation is IDs must be unique and can't be numeric.

Comment: However, part of your issue may be that you are repeating ids.  Ids are expected to be unique per page.

Comment: @Taplar It really doesn´t matter because both functions works, my problem here is that only the first line of my list works, but I will edit the question to post that code too.

Comment: If both your methods worked, you wouldn't have a question here on S.O.  `document.querySelector('form#ed')` is only going to find the first form on the page.  It will not find any of the other forms on the page with the same id on them

Comment: *"It really doesn´t matter because both functions works,"* Famous last words

Comment: Also as a side note; do not do `querySelectorAll('[class="buttonDelete"]')`.  You are performing a class lookup, using an attribute selector, which is not going to have the performance gains that browsers offer when using a class selector.  Instead, using the attribute selector, you are making the browser perform a DOM scan as any element could have that class.  Using `querySelectorAll('.buttonDelete')` will let the browser use whatever internal cache it has for all the elements to find those that have the class, much more efficiently.

Comment: @Taplar Ok I was looking this in a wrong way, because I did not see that each line is a different form, so my question here is how could I work with a dynamic id?

Comment: Just use `document.querySelectorAll(".class");` and you won't need to worry about the form itself.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you! With your comments I could understand how forms and querySelector function work and now the code is running great.

Comment: @imvain2 Thank you, I did what you said and now everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Taplar and @imvain2 I could get an answer to this question and understand how this works. THANK YOU GUYS!

Here is the final code

```
const userDel  = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonDelete');
const userEdit = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonEdit');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners(event) {
    userDel.forEach(buttonDel => {
        buttonDel.addEventListener('click', markDeleted);
    });

    userEdit.forEach(buttonEdit => {
        buttonEdit.addEventListener('click', userEdited);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every row contains a separate form, so using an id to select them will only select the first one.

So, you can replace this

```
const userDel = formEditDel.querySelectorAll('[class="buttonDelete"]')
const userEdit = formEditDel.querySelectorAll('[class="buttonEdit"]')
```

With this

```
const userDel = document.querySelectorAll('[class="buttonDelete"]')
const userEdit = document.querySelectorAll('[class="buttonEdit"]')
```

Or you can replace this

```
<form id="ed" method="POST"> ... </form>
```

With this

```
<form class="ed" method="POST"> ... </form>
```

And then select the form using class

```
const formEditDel = document.querySelector('form.ed');
```